# Unity: Building different meshes using the same class - error

Tags: class, reference, unity-game-engine, instance, mesh

- FIXED *  Here is the code where i call a class that generates a patch of terrain. When i call a single object, it works, but here it doesn't show anything. I've tried other methods and usually the last called object gets to be displayed. You'll find the main code and the class code below:

`
public class MainLoop : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float jagginess;
public int   patch_segments;

GameObject ter1;
GameObject ter2;

CMesh cmesh1;
CMesh cmesh2;

void Start () {
    ter1 = new GameObject();
    ter2 = new GameObject();

    patch_segments = 64;
    jagginess = 1.3f;

    cmesh1 = ter1.GetComponent<CMesh>();
    cmesh2 = ter2.GetComponent<CMesh>();
}


void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {

        cmesh1.init(patch_segments, 0, 0);
        cmesh1.applyDiamondSquare(jagginess);
        cmesh1.build();

        cmesh2.init(patch_segments, 100, 100);
        cmesh2.applyDiamondSquare(jagginess);
        cmesh2.build();
    }
}
```

}
`

and the Mesh class:

`

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
//[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]

public class CMesh : MonoBehaviour {


        Mesh mesh;

        Texture2D heightMap;

        float x_pos;
        float z_pos;
        int segments;

        public Vector3 scaleSegments = new Vector3(200, 100, 200);

        Vector3 vertex;
        Vector3[] vertices;
        Vector3[] normals;
        Vector2[] uv;
        int[] triangles;

        Vector3 camera_position;

        public void init(int mesh_segments, float position_x, float position_z) {

            x_pos = position_x;
            z_pos = position_z;

            mesh = new Mesh();

            GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh = new Mesh();
            mesh.name = "Star Mesh";

            //camera_position = GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").GetComponent<cameraMovement>().camera_pos;

            //scaleSegments = new Vector3(200, 100, 200);

            segments = mesh_segments;

            initHeightMap();
        }

        public void build() {

            int x, z;

            int vsize_x = segments+1;
            int vsize_z = segments+1;

            int numVerts = vsize_x*vsize_z;
            int numQuads = segments*segments;
            int numTriangles = numQuads*2;

            vertices  = new Vector3[numVerts];
            normals   = new Vector3[numVerts];
            uv        = new Vector2[numVerts];
            triangles = new int[numTriangles*3];

            Vector2 uvScale    = new Vector2(1.0f/(vsize_x - 1), 1.0f/(vsize_z - 1));
            Vector3 vertsScale = new Vector3(scaleSegments.x / (vsize_x - 1), scaleSegments.y, scaleSegments.z / (vsize_z - 1));

            //Build vertices, normals and uv's
            for (z = 0; z < vsize_z; z++) {
                for (x = 0; x < vsize_x; x++) {
                    vertex = Vector3.Scale(vertsScale, new Vector3(x_pos + x, heightMap.GetPixel(x, z).r, z_pos + z));
                    vertices [z*vsize_x + x] = vertex + new Vector3(x_pos, 0, z_pos);
                    normals  [z*vsize_x + x] = Vector3.up;
                    uv       [z*vsize_x + x] = Vector2.Scale(new Vector2(x, z), uvScale);   
                }
            }
            //Build triangles
            int index = 0;
            for (z = 0; z < vsize_z - 1; z++) {
                for (x = 0; x < vsize_x - 1; x++) {

                    triangles[index++] = (z * vsize_x) + x;
                    triangles[index++] = ((z+1) * vsize_x) + x;
                    triangles[index++] = (z * vsize_x) + x + 1;

                    triangles[index++] = ((z+1) * vsize_x) + x;
                    triangles[index++] = ((z+1) * vsize_x) + x + 1;
                    triangles[index++] = (z * vsize_x) + x + 1;
                }
            }

            mesh.vertices = vertices;
            mesh.triangles = triangles;
            mesh.normals = normals;
            mesh.uv = uv;


            //MeshFilter   mesh_filter   = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            //MeshRenderer mesh_renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            //MeshCollider mesh_collider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();

            //mesh_filter.mesh = mesh;
        }
`
```

Comment: `cmesh2 = ter2.GetComponent<CMesh>();` (same for `ter1`) won't work in this context.  `ter2` is instantiated as a new (no components) `GameObject`.

Comment: I've fixed it by creating a new gameobject inside the class in the init() function and by adding a renderer component. Thanks anyways